# How do i send a class through TCP socket in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I have a class named "Packet" with variables:

```
{
  int length;
  char *data;//(length)
}
```

I want to send it through a tcp socket like:

```
 send(socket_id, <myclass>, <length data>, 0);
```

How can I do it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to serialize your objects to a byte stream and then send that byte stream.

If you can make your objects conform to the [`NSCoding` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/) then you can get this up and running pretty quickly.

Check out Apple's [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html).